# Google Calendar unrecognized entries

Tags: security, google-calendar

My Google Calendar has a 4 AM entry for every day that appears to be in the Cyrillic alphabet. I did not make these entries. Is this a known hack?
[image]

Comment: [Spam events appear in my Google Calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/42661/45867) and [How do I really stop Gmail adding events to Google Calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74367/45867)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a known issue with people sending you spam. Due to how Gmail and Google Calendar interact, some spam emails containing dates can be automatically added to your calendar.

If you want to stop it, there is a quick article [here](https://www.theverge.com/2019/8/23/20829615/google-calendar-spam-events-sharing-email-how-to-stop) that gives you a work around to stop them.